# Is there an example of two graphs with the same Dichromatic Symmetric Function?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-colorings, symmetric-functions

There are examples of two graphs with the same Symmetric Chromatic Function. I was wondering if there was an example that held for the Dichromatic Symmetric Chromatic Function.

EDIT :

To define the Symmetric Chromatic Function, first consider the graph $G(V,E)$. Then a coloring of $G$ is a function $\kappa:V\rightarrow C=\mathbb{N}$. A coloring of $G$, $\kappa$, is proper if for all $ij:=\{i,j\}\in E$, $\kappa(i)\neq\kappa(j)$. Then the Symmetric Chromatic Function is a symmetric function in a (countably) infinite number of (commuting) variables $$X_G(x_1,x_2,...)=\sum_{\kappa \text{ proper }} x_{\kappa}$$ where $x_{\kappa}=x_{\kappa(v_1)}x_{\kappa(v_2)}...x_{\kappa(v_m)}$.

The Dichromatic Symmetric Chromatic Function is defined as $$X_G(t)=\sum_{\kappa} x_{\kappa}(1+t)^{bad(\kappa)},$$ where $bad(\kappa)$ is the number of edges that are colored improperly. One of the key differences is that multiedges aren't the same as single edges.

For more information on the symmetric chromatic function see http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/pubs/pubfiles/100.pdf. Prof. Stanley gives an example of two graphs with the same Symmetric Chromatic Function in this paper, which also introduced the Symmetric Chromatic Function. For some information about the Dichromatic Symmetric Function see http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/papers/taor.pdf, section 3.1. For some information about graphs with the same Symmetric Chromatic Function, see

*Orellana, Rosa; Scott, Geoffrey*, [**Graphs with equal chromatic symmetric functions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2013.12.006), Discrete Math. 320, 1-14 (2014). [ZBL1281.05064](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1281.05064).

Comment: What is the definition of the Dichromatic Symmetric Chromatic Function? How does it differ from the Chromatic Symmetric Function?

Comment: What is $x_{\cal K}$?

Comment: I have added a lot more information, thanks for pointing out that I should!